# This version does not have support for IRIs while running wget

Tags: wget, iri

While executing the below code

timeout 900 wget --random-wait --tries=2 --timeout=90 --recursive --level=1 --no-parent --follow-tags=a \
--html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --force-directories \
--reject jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,gif,GIF,pdf,PDF,zip,ZIP,png,PNG,css,CSS,js,JS,mp4,MP4,wmv,WMV,mp3,MP3,aac,AAC,mpeg,MPEG,flv,FLV,m4v,M4V,wav,WAV,svg,SVG,exe,EXE,rar,RAR \
--local-encoding=UTF-8 --header="Accept-Charset: utf-8" \
  www.google.com

I am getting This version does not have support for IRIs error. my wget version is 1.12. Can you please help me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 0):

- in terminal:
- try "wget -V"  (e.g.:)
  :~$ wget -V

GNU Wget **1.17.1** built on linux-gnu.

+digest -gpgme +https +ipv6 **+iri** +large-file -metalink +nls +ntlm 
+opie -psl +ssl/openssl

Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Originally written by Hrvoje Niksic .
Please send **bug reports and questions to

bug-wget@gnu.org.**